# How to assign random numbers (0,1) with pre-determined counts for different intervals in Python

Tags: python, random

I am using Python.
I have read in this dataset:

[image]

I need to randomly assigned 0 and 1 values such that:

- for a score between 100 and 109: the count of 0's is 2 and the count of 1's is 4
- for a score above 109: the count of 0's is 2 and the count of 1's is 2

So, ultimately, the dataset might look like this:

[image: Id Score Target 1 100 0 2 104 1 3 104 1 4 106 1 5 106 0 6 109 1 7 113 0 8 115 1 9 115 1 10 116 0]

Again, the Target values (0,1) are randomly assigned but their total count has to sum up to the pre-determined counts: there have to be TWO zero's and FOUR ones when the score is <= 109 an there have to be TWO zero's and TWO one's when the score is greater than 109.

I have tried to combine two arrays (for example: np.concatenate((np.zeros(10), np.ones(23))), but I don't know how to structure it.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: You are expected to add data as text since we can not copy the contents from image.

Comment: can we assume there are only 10 data points? are there more subdivisions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your score is always sorted so you know the length of the two lists, you can start with two fixed lists and shuffle them randomly, then concatenate them.

```
from random import shuffle
less_than = [0,0,1,1,1,1]
greater_than = [0,0,1,1]
shuffle(less_than)
shuffle(greater_than)
target = less_than+greater_than
```

target should be a list that represents the assigned values of 0 and 1 that you are looking for and the sums should be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
```

I'll assume you have a `numpy` `ndarray` as follows:

```py
arr = np.array([100, 104, 104, 106, 106, 109, 113, 115, 115, 116])
```

Then grab the indices where some condition matches:

```py
indices = np.where((100 <= arr) & (arr <= 109))[0] # np.where returns a tuple, so grab 0th

# False disables sample replacement
randomly_selected_indices = np.random.choice(indices, 4, False)
```

Finally, set a new array at your random indices to 1.

```py
score = np.zeros(10)
score[randomly_selected_indices] = 1
```